# Invoke Delegate separate class progress bar

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates, progress-bar

I'm loading a large amount of data from a separate project and would like to display the progress to the user.

So as each piece of data is loaded, I'd like to pass that event back from a Framework Class, back to the main winform, then to the separate dialog progress bar form.

There would be three things passed back:

1. Status message
2. Current status count
3. Total Items to process.

All I need to know is how to pass this information back and where the delegates should go.

```
List<myObject> objListFoo = new List<myObject>();
FormLoadingProgress frmProgress = new FormLoadingProgress();
frmProgress.ShowInTaskBar = false;
frmProgress.Show();

Framework.Foo objFoo = new Framework.Foo();
objFoo.DoEvent(); // <-- This takes 10-60 seconds
objListFoo = objFoo.GetData();

frmProgress.Close();
frmProgress.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's an example showing exactly what you need to do.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar)

The only thing you need to adjust in that example is the method call to ReportProgress. In your case, you'll probably want to call [this version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx), which receives an int and an object. In that object you can pass in whatever information you need (1. Status message, 2. Current status count, 3. Total Items to process.)